# Symfony 1.4 query builder single character explanation

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4, builder

i am just doing **jobeet** tutorial but I bit confused by **single character** used in query builder :

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->select(' j .*')     //what is j ?
  ->from('JobeetJob j')
  ->leftJoin('j.JobeetCategory c') //what is c ?
  ->leftJoin('c.JobeetAffiliates a'); //what is a ?
  ->where('a.id = ?', $this->getId());
```

What are the meaning of **j, c, a** in that query builder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j` is your alias for `JobeetJob` table defined in a line:

```
->from('JobeetJob j')
```

the same goes for `c` being an alias for `JobeetCategory` table, and `a` for `JobeetAffiliates`. These aliases can be whatever you like, so your query may also look like:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->select(' qwerty .*')     
  ->from('JobeetJob qwerty')
  ->leftJoin('qwerty.JobeetCategory asdf') 
  ->leftJoin('asdf.JobeetAffiliates zxcv'); 
  ->where('zxcv.id = ?', $this->getId());
```

Comment: thanks for Tomasz, I understand now, but I have another question if you do not mind I have a bit more question, why both left join are not :   ->leftJoin('qwerty.JobeetCategory asdf') 
  ->leftJoin('qwerty.JobeetAffiliates zxcv');

Comment: I don't know your model, but probably that's because your db is designed this way: `JobeetJob` has relation to `JobeetCategory` and `JobeetCategory` has relation to `JobeetAffiliates` (and not `JobeetJob` having relation to `JobeetAffiliates`). To verify that check your `schema.yml` file where your model (with relations) is defined